# Excel Application Property using in Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I want to generate and format an excel workbook out of access. The creation of the file is done easy, but I struggle with the format.

file creation
    Dim strCurrentDBName As String

```
strCurrentDBName = CurrentDb.Name
For i = Len(strCurrentDBName) To 1 Step -1
   If Mid(strCurrentDBName, i, 1) = "\" Then
      strPath = Left(strCurrentDBName, i)
      Exit For
   End If
Next
xlsxPath = strPath & "Report.xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Report", xlsxPath, True

MsgBox ("Report generated. " & xlsxPath)
```

format

```
Dim xl As Object
'This deals with Excel already being open or not
On Error Resume Next
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xl Is Nothing Then
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

Set XlBook = GetObject(xlsxPath)
'filename is the string with the link to the file ("C:/....blahblah.xls")

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
xl.Visible = True
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
'xl.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set xlsheet1 = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

'Format
With xlsheet1
    xlsheet1.Rows("1:1").Select
```

and here is my error (Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error)

```
    xlsheet1.Range(xl.Selection, xl.Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    xlsheet1.Selection.EntireRow.AutoFit

End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `xlDown` enum value, which requires a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library. Since you're using late bindings, that reference probably isn't set.

Work around it by using the value of `xlDown`, -4121:

```
xlsheet1.Range(xl.Selection, xl.Selection.End(-4121)).Select
```

Note that this error would've been more easy to spot if you had put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.